# Best practice to choose primary keys in a relational DB, what is the smartest solution?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, primary-key

I am designing a relational DB and I have the following doubt about what is the best practice for handling primary keys

I have some tables where the only way to have a primary key is to set a `BIGINT autoincrement` column named `id`.

Other table contains univocal data (for example I have a `Country` table containing an univocal `country_code` column) that can be used as primary key.

My question is: what is the best practice in this case? I still use a `BIGINT autoincrement` column named `id` or in this case is better to use the univocal data as primary key?

Comment: Nothing lasts forever, not even countries or country codes.

Comment: @jarlh so an ID is better?

Comment: I'd probably say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if a table has a good natural key, it is still generally preferable to assign a surrogate key (usually a numeric auto increment column).

First, as jarlh points out, even countries can and do change their names from time to time, which you can handle easily with a `CountryID` value.

Also, though, many times a natural key is composed of character data. SQL deals with numbers faster than it deals with characters, so there is a performance boost using numeric ID values.

And it's currently the standard practice in data warehousing, so developers are accustomed to seeing those SK columns.

Best practice? Probably. Standard practice? Definitely. Go with the autoincrements.

Answer (score 0):

There's an entire topic in computer science known as *database normalization,* where they discuss things like "first, second, and third normal forms."

A staple of this is that database keys should not, themselves, carry information.  They should "unambiguously identify the row" and nothing more.  So, an auto-increment integer is a good thing to use as a primary key.  Then, place an index ... perhaps a `UNIQUE` index ... on `country_code`.

In other applications, I have used things like `uuid's` ... guaranteed-unique identifier strings ... as primary keys.  The database generates the uuid value automagically.  Now I have something that I can *transport* from one database to another without ambiguity.  (I have also used auto-generated `uuid` *fields* in databases that used auto-increment keys.)

So, you do have several good alternatives, but in every case the primary-key *only* identifies the row and is not "part of the data."

Comment: "A staple of this is that database keys should not, themselves, carry information." That has nothing to do with normalization & it's not correct about design either.